# (Cross-Platform) 3D Programming with C# (mono)

Tags: c#, mono, 3d, cross-platform

I'm looking for a 3d engine (for games). I prefer C# with .net or Mono but C++ would also do it if I don't find anything for C#. I want to code programs for Windows and Linux. iPhone/Android would also be interesting for other projects.

So far I found these engines (C#):

- Axiom - This one seems pretty fair and since it's a C# port of OGRE3D it should offer basic function (I'm quite a beginner in 3D so I don't need much functions). It's Windows and Linux :), don't know about Mac, It's Open Source
- Unity - I think the engine itself is written in C++, but I'm not sure. But you can write the game in C# :) and JavaScript. It's Windows and Mac and some other platforms like iPhone, ... but no Linux. And I don't know how much you can do in the free version. It's not open source
- XNA, it's for Windows only but there is MONO.XNA but I think this project is dead.

Are there some other engines I could use in C#?
Axiom seems to be what I need. Someone got experience with Axiom?
Which one would you choose?

Thanks!

Edit:
It would be cool if the program built with the engine/framework doesn't require any runtime program installed (except .net or mono)
As far as I know you need to install XNA to run XNA applications. :(

Comment: Mono.Xna is unfortunately very dead. I would help to resurrect it if I had the relevant know-how.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) for a good baseline OpenGL graphics library. Documentation is [here](http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/0) as well as a similar post from [GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=472052).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Irrlicht Engine](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/features.html).

I think it has everything you are asking for (Opensource, platform independent, etc. ). I only used it for a small project in the past, but I know it has a very good renderer system. The engine doesn't have a Level Editor itself but you buy it as an add-on application.

For Irrlicht/Mono integration, [look here](http://irrlichtnetcp.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page).

For iPhone/Android, I think your best bet is going with [Unity](http://www.unity3d.com). As you stated, it isn't open source, but I have found nothing easier than this spectacular engine.

Comment: IrrlichtNetCP is not actually a good option if you're looking for .Net support and cross-platform.  I tried getting it to work on Linux, but the only "support" it has is a very simplistic makefile that fails to build.  Obviously, Linux support was only an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild suggestion, but you could try to do it using the canvas-element in html5. You'll be able to do the same things as you can using C++/OpenGL, but using JavaScript directly in the browser. Of course you wont be able to get it to perform quite as well as you could using C++, but portability will be great; no frameworks to install and anyone with a browser (regardless of OS) can play it.

Here's a couple of great [tutorials](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217)

Dont forget that you'll get the good and bad parts of being bleeding edge...

Comment: Well, if that is the case you better go with Unity, it is super powerful and can deploy games using a web plugin (Linux included). But, if I understand correctly the question, games on the browser are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) framework fully supports [OpenGL](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtopengl.html). It's C++. It's not exactly an engine, but you may be able to plug in some other engines into your source.

I am new to Qt as of a few weeks to a month ago, also coming from a heavy C# background. There were some hurdles are first (mostly compiler-based head scratchers) but beyond that I have completely fallen in love with it. I tried things like Java and Python when I was looking to go cross-platform, but Qt is where I settled.

Answer (score 0):

I was once a great fan of OGRE - maybe it's worthwhile to check if [MOGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MOGRE) is supported on Mono.

EDIT:

Well, I checked, and it says that it isn't :( .  Guys are recommending AXIOM instead.